# Do I need to improve the quality of my questions or does it normally take time to get feedback on questions here?

Tags: discussion

I have felt that the questions I post on the Unix & Linux website do not get enough views and/or responses in comparison with other stack exchange websites.

I am not sure if it is because my questions are not properly framed (or the tags I use are not popular on this website) or if  "Unix & Linux" is not as populated as other websites.

**My motive is not to blame or criticize this website or its members**. I genuinely want to know how I can get the most out of this website.

EDIT:
I posted this question [yesterday](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352466/why-do-i-see-unable-to-locate-tools-jar-expected-to-find-it-in-when-i-ru/352514#352514) and I did not get feedback from any of the users.

Comment: This is probably better to post on the meta side of this SE website since it's a question about the website itself. In general, though Stack Exchange websites are ran on a volunteer basis. Sometimes people are going to know how to answer your question, other times not. Sometimes there'll be someone who knows the answer but doesn't want to write up a response, etc, etc. It's free support so you take what you get. That question might have gotten more visibility if you had deleted the U&L question and posted it to Stack Overflow which specializes in programming related questions.

Comment: Stack Overflow also has a lot more users, so the odds of finding a knowledgeable person who feels like responding is probably better. U&L wasn't that bad of a choice but you can see people voting to close it because building java apps is usually a skill unto itself regardless of the platform you're on.

Comment: @Bratchley Thank you for the reply. Your comments have what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I left a comment as to what's wrong with your script in `/etc/profile.d` on your answer. See that for your actual issue. Your question is fair enough for this site, but given it's fairly basic some people just might not be inclined to help. As @Bratchley has stated, this site is run by volunteers, so if someone helps it's of their own accord.

In the future you might want to boil your question down to a more simplistic issue you're experiencing, by framing it in terms of a Java issue that deters people that may have helped you in answering, since on the surface they might be inclined to think that its a Java issue when it's really a Bash and/or `/etc/profile.d` issue.

Comment: Thank you. This is a very helpful answer.